# React native Detox build failed

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I try to add Detox to my project and I followed the setup, but it failed in build[image]

what should I do?

I tried this command `cd android ; ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug ;`  ,
and it executed correctly

this is .detoxrc.js

```js
/** @type {Detox.DetoxConfig} */
module.exports = {
  testRunner: {
    args: {
      '$0': 'jest',
      config: 'e2e/jest.config.js'
    },
    jest: {
      setupTimeout: 120000
    }
  },
  apps: {
    'ios.debug': {
      type: 'ios.app',
      binaryPath: 'ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YOUR_APP.app',
      build: 'xcodebuild -workspace ios/YOUR_APP.xcworkspace -scheme YOUR_APP -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build'
    },
    'ios.release': {
      type: 'ios.app',
      binaryPath: 'ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/YOUR_APP.app',
      build: 'xcodebuild -workspace ios/YOUR_APP.xcworkspace -scheme YOUR_APP -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build'
    },
    'android.debug': {
      type: 'android.apk',
      binaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
      build: 'cd android ; ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug ; cd -',
      /*reversePorts: [
        8081
      ]*/
    },
    'android.release': {
      type: 'android.apk',
      binaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk',
      build: 'cd android ; ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release ; cd -'
    }
  },
  devices: {
    simulator: {
      type: 'ios.simulator',
      device: {
        type: 'iPhone 12'
      }
    },
    attached: {
      type: 'android.attached',
      device: {
        adbName: '.*'
      }
    },
    emulator: {
      type: 'android.emulator',
      device: {
        avdName: 'Pixel_3a_API_30'
      }
    }
  },
  configurations: {
    'ios.sim.debug': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.debug'
    },
    'ios.sim.release': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.release'
    },
    'android.att.debug': {
      device: 'attached',
      app: 'android.debug'
    },
    'android.att.release': {
      device: 'attached',
      app: 'android.release'
    },
    'android.emu.debug': {
      device: 'emulator',
      app: 'android.debug'
    },
    'android.emu.release': {
      device: 'emulator',
      app: 'android.release'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please add .detoxrc.json file here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with you configuration command
use `&&` instead of `;`

Like

```
"android.debug": {
  type: "android.apk",
  binaryPath: "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
  build:
    "cd android && gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
},
```

Comment: thanks, it works with a little change :
cd android && gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..